# Update values in second table after editing in first table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables **Department** and **Employee**

In **Department** table I have DepartmentId and DepartmentName.
In **Employee** table I have EmployeeId, EmployeeName, DepartmentName

I do a mini project in .NET and I also use some SQL queries for edit, add etc.

*What I want to do?*

If I edit the DepartmentName in **Department** table, I want to update also in **Employee** the DepartmentName for all employees who are assigned to that DepartmentName.

For example if I edit the DepName from **Department** table from Support to CallCenter, I want to update it also in the same time in **Employee** table for all employees who are in Support department

Department table

```
+----------+----------+
| DepId    | DepName  |
+----------+----------+
|        1 | Support  |
|        2 | Testing  |
|        3 | HR       |
+----------+----------+
```

Employee Table

| EmployeeId | EmployeeName | DepName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon | Support |
| 2 | Mike | Testing |
| 3 | Patrick | HR |
| 4 | Mark | Support |

Can you help me with a solution/query for this?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: don't save the department name save the department number and all problems will be asolved

Comment: I suggest you spend some time learning how to design relational databases. This is a skill that must be learned - it does not magically happen by learning SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the department name, you will need to save the department ID number so you can join the tables/ connect them/ match rows etc.

Then you will want to create a trigger so that when your department table is updated, your Employee table is also updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
    BEFORE UPDATE 
    ON DepartmentTableName
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   if :new.deptid != :old.deptid
   then
       UPDATE EmployeeTable e
       set e.deptid = :new.deptid
       where e.deptid = :new.id;
    end if;
END;
```

Granted, this trigger is if you are changing the ID numbers.

If you simply connect the two tables with a foreign key in the employee table connecting it to the department table primary key, then every time you edit the actual name of the department, because the department ID stays the same, the corrected name of the department will be transferred when you join tables because the tables are connected by ID and not by the actual name of the department.